# Android : Assigning a high resolution image to a smaller ImageView

Tags: android, image

I have this unanswered question of mine pertaining to images. I have an image of about 1 MB and I am assigning the images to an image view with width and height of `100dp and 80dp` respectively. But when I assign the image to about 5 image views, the application crashes with `Out of Memory Error`

So, when I assign the 1 MB image to such a small image view, what happens? Doesn't android scale it down? Also, did the app crash because it couldn't take the load of 5MB in memory??

**EDIT**
I have 5 ImageViews on the screen. I am assigning the image to all if them this way

```
myImageView.setImageURI(item.getImageUri());
```

Comment: Which folder(s) is the image in? Is it `drawable`?

Comment: @Lamorak : No, I am reading the images from ExternalStorage URI

Comment: Then my answer should be sufficient to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Android loads the whole image file to the memory and then scales it down. In order to avoid OOM you should [load large bitmaps efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap).

Comment: no, `ImageView` doesn't scale the Bitmaps, instead it "scales" its Canvas to draw the image Drawable in different sizes

Comment: @pskink : So, the size of the image still remains 1MB even though it is shown in such a small imageview!!?

Comment: @Ashwin yes, `ImageView` doesn't touch the input `Bitmap`

Comment: @pskink : Okay. I should do some more research on this. I always thought that lesser a smaller image occupies less size.